# How to get value of command arugment using javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkprogress" runat="server" class="label label-info"  BackColor="#589FC2"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("BookingId")%>'  OnClientClick="jk();" >In progress</asp:LinkButton>
```

This button exist in repeater for every row.I want to get the value of command argument using javascript.please reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkprogress" runat="server" class="label label-info"  
    BackColor="#589FC2" data-CommandArgument='<%#Eval("BookingId")%>'
    OnClientClick="jk();" >In progress</asp:LinkButton>
```

Using Javascript:

```
document.getElementsId("lnkprogress")[0].getAttribute("CommandArgument")
```

[Check this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp)

Using jQuery:

```
$('#lnkprogress').data('CommandArgument');
```

Comment: Hey I'm guessing you are not an asp.net programmer. The `CommandArgument` is used by the system so you cant rename it to `data-CommandArgument`. If you look at my reply then you will see I have duplicated it instead.

Comment: Ok..You are correct..[In detail](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using html5 data attributes like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkprogress" runat="server" class="label label-info"  BackColor="#589FC2"  data-bookingid='<%#Eval("BookingId")%>'  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("BookingId")%>'  OnClientClick="jk();" >In progress</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then retrieve it using some JavaScript like this:

```
var lnkProgress = document.getElementById('<%= lnkProgress.ClientID %>');
var bookingID = lnkProgress.getAttribute("data-bookingid");
```

Although I'm assuming that your lnkProgress is going to be inside a naming container like one of the databound controls so it might not be as easy as `getElementById('<%= lnkProgress.ClientID %>');` to get a reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

Add an html5 attribute as suggested by rtpHarry and send the control as a parameter in OnClientClick:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkprogress" runat="server" class="label label-info"  `BackColor="#589FC2"  data-bookingid='<%#Eval("BookingId")%>'  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("BookingId")%>'  OnClientClick="javascript: jk(this);" >In progress</asp:LinkButton>
```

In your function just reference the control attribute:

```
function jk(ctrl) {
            var id = ctrl.getAttribute("data-bookingid");
        }
```

By sending the control as a parameter you don't have to worry if the linkbutton is inside another container, i.e. gridview.